# Why CreateAsync of AuthenticationTokenProvider Is Called When Request to Exchange RefreshToken Arrives?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, owin

I have custom implementation of `AuthenticationTokenProvider` abstraction. It has two methods to be overriden that I'm using: `CreateAsync`, `ReceiveAsync`.

In `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` I have `RefreshTokenProvider` set to my custom `AuthenticationTokenProvider` implementation.

My access tokens expire in 20 minutes. My refresh tokens expire in 24 hours. When access token expires a request comes with `grant_type=refresh_token` containing refresh token. I observe `ReceiveAsync` is called. There is a logic of setting `Ticket` property of `AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext`. But afterwards `CreateAsync` method is called, where there is a logic of setting token in `AuthenticationTokenCreateContext`. The `Ticket` property of `AuthenticationTokenCreateContext` does not seem to be that one I have set previously in `ReceiveAsync` method.

As a result I receive response with new access token and refresh token. I don't want refresh token to be reissued each time I want to exchange my access token, I already have one valid for 24 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I have found how to answer my question. I can leverage `OwinContext.Environment` to store a flag which tells that my refresh token is not expired yet so there is no need of creation a new one.

```
public class RefreshTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    private const string IsRefreshTokenExpiredName = "IsRefreshTokenExpired";

    #region ctor
    public RefreshTokenProvider()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    public async override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        if (!context.OwinContext.Environment.ContainsKey(IsRefreshTokenExpiredName) || (bool)context.OwinContext.Environment[IsRefreshTokenExpiredName])
        {
            var hours = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshTokenExpirationHours"]);
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = now;
            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = now.AddHours(hours);
            context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
        }
    }

    public async override Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorsOrigins"] });
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Method", new[] { "POST" });

        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
        if (context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc > DateTime.UtcNow)
            context.OwinContext.Environment[IsRefreshTokenExpiredName] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer having a smaller window for a bad actor obtaining the refresh token and being able to exchange for an access token. In addition, if the refresh token is also exchanged, the previous refresh token is invalid.  If the previous refresh token is used, all associated tokens are invalidated including the access token.